# Can I deploy a flutter web app on firebase hosting with Navigator 1.0?

Tags: flutter, firebase-hosting

So I am making a flutter web app that I want to deploy with firebase hosting. However, do I need to use Navigator 2.0 to do so, or is Navigator 1.0 fine. Thank you for helping.

Edit:
My concern with the navigator is due to the links, since in Navigator 1.0, you can push an unamed routes, would that affect the website when for example; I refresh the page and am taken back to the home page or would firebase hosting create links for me.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Hosting has no knowledge of the fact that your use Flutter. So if it works on another static web host, it will also work on Firebase Hosting. If you have any issues running your Flutter web app that are specific to Firebase Hosting, I'd recommend posting a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I understand, however I believe I didn´t explain myself correctly. What I meant was not exactly regarding the hosting iteslf but the links. Since with navigator 2.0 you generate the links yourself, would there be any problem with them if I used navigator 1.0. I edited the question to be more clear, and thank you for taking the time